# In reference to the calculation, should one use "mean" or "mean of"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, mathematics, statistics

I am writing a scientific paper and am unsure if I should be using "mean" or "mean of" each time I refer to a calculated mean number.

For example, should it be:

```
A) The samples had a mean of 54.1 reads

B) The samples had a mean 54.1 reads
```

Or how about:

```
C) A mean of 54.1 reads were generated

D) A mean 54.1 reads were generated
```

After reading through a few scientific articles it looks like both are used, but is one more correct or preferred? Does it change the meaning?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: To me (British English) "a mean of 54.1 reads" looks, reads, and sounds better.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the examples are all very poor, to the extent that the posted question can't be answered. The Q also lacks context and evidence of effort. While not the intent of the question, it amounts to proofreading/writing advice since the sentences need to be rewritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mean of** is idiomatic in the scientific literature, as are **value of**, **mass of**, **weight of**, **length of**, **duration of**, etc.

No one would use your C) and D) in a scientific paper. You didn't generate the mean. Rather, you generated (that is, made or conducted) a set of observations, and you then calculated the mean of the values of the resulting set, which happened to be 54.1 reads. You wouldn't *a priori* generate a set with a **mean of** 54.1 reads.